# How to make if statement check each for loop statement for valid input

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
import random
max_value = input("I'm going to pick a number. You have to try and guess the same number that I pick. Guess right and win a prize. What is the highest number I can pick? ")
computer_choice = random.randint(1, int(max_value))

for (computer_choice) in range(1,6):
    user_choice = input("What number between 1 and " + max_value + " do you choose? ")
    if user_choice == computer_choice:
        print("Thank you for playing. ")
```

Needs to give the user 5 chances to give the computer_choice before failing. For loop is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a counter which will keep the track of the number of attemps that user has made so far.

Also need to convert user input from string to int type.

```
import random
max_value = int(input("I'm going to pick a number. You have to try and guess the same number that I pick. Guess right and win a prize. What is the highest number I can pick? "))
computer_choice = random.randint(1, int(max_value))
count = 0
for (computer_choice) in range(1,6):
    user_choice = int(input("What number between 1 and " + max_value + " do you choose? "))
    count += 1
    if user_choice == computer_choice:
        print("Thank you for playing. ")
    if count==5:
         print("you have reached maximum attempt limit")
         exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the for loop with separate variable then computer_choice. Also add eval to input statement as it gives string to conert the user_choice to integer and add a break statement in if user_choice == computer_choice to end the program, rest should work fine.

```
import random
max_value = input("I'm going to pick a number. You have to try and guess the same number that I pick. Guess right and win a prize. What is the highest number I can pick? ")
computer_choice = random.randint(1, int(max_value))

for (i) in range(1,6):
    #input takes string convert choice to int using eval
    user_choice = eval(input("What number between 1 and " + max_value + " do you choose? "))
    if user_choice == computer_choice:
        print("Thank you for playing. ")
        break
    if(i==5):
        print("Sorry, maximum number of tries reached.")
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach:

```
import random
max_value = input("I'm going to pick a number. You have to try and guess the same number that I pick. Guess right and win a prize. What is the highest number I can pick? ")
computer_choice = random.randint(1, int(max_value))

for i in range(1,6):
    user_choice = input("What number between 1 and " + max_value + " do you choose? ")
    if int(user_choice) == int(computer_choice):
        print("Right choice. Thank you for playing. ")
        break
    elif(i == 5):
        print ("Sorry, maximum attempts reached...")
        break
    else:
        print ("Oops, wrong choice, pls choose again...")
```

Output:

```
I'm going to pick a number. You have to try and guess the same number that I pick. Guess right and win a prize. What is the highest number I can pick? 5
What number between 1 and 5 do you choose? 1
Oops, wrong choice, pls choose again...
What number between 1 and 5 do you choose? 3
Oops, wrong choice, pls choose again...
What number between 1 and 5 do you choose? 4
Oops, wrong choice, pls choose again...
What number between 1 and 5 do you choose? 5
Oops, wrong choice, pls choose again...
What number between 1 and 5 do you choose? 6
Sorry, maximum attempts reached...
```